# Maximum parallel queries in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I'm new in Cassandra DB, and I have a very trivial question: how much parallel queries can O do without compromising perfomance? The queries are going to be like

```
Select data from table where id='asdasdasd';
```

Its a server in a datacenter, it should work properly with 3000 read querys? Sorry for the poor information but its all i have.

Comment: no way to answer this. if your db is powered by a hamster in a rusty wheel, one query will probably kill the system. anything bigger/less rusty will be able to handle, obviously, more queries.

Comment: You should cap your in flight requests to a certain number (use a semaphore etc.) That will maximize throughput.

Comment: Its a server in a datacenter, it should work properly with 3000 read querys? Sorry for the poor information but its all i have.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the server's capacity where you have installed your cluster of Cassandra, and how you have configured the nodes.

There is a configuration parameter in **cassandra.yaml** that is **concurrent_reads** 
Tune it to get a better read rate.

Comment: Its a server in a datacenter, it should work properly with 3000 read querys? Sorry for the poor information but its all i have.

Comment: with so much limited information, there is no way to answer.